# Understanding changes in bookings per medical practice

Tags: time-series, modeling

I have data for counts of bookings per day.
I have data for counts of active medical pracitces per day (active means that they have published appointments that are able to be booked in the past 28 days).

Bookings can occur 24/7 and the number of practices is constantly changing (new people starting to publish etc).

I am trying to understand bookings per practice over a 28 day period.

I have two options (open to calculating this in a completely different way if it is justified) that I am trying to decide between.

Option 1:

bookings per practice over a 28 day period = sum preceeding 28 (bookings on day x)/(28 day MA of active practices)

Option 2:
sum last 28 days of (bookings on day x/active practices day x)

Option 2 is using this logic: http://www.shopify.com/technology/4018382-defining-churn-rate-no-really-this-actually-requires-an-entire-blog-post#axzz34NyuLe1Q

I feel like option 2 is 'better' than option 1.

Reason:
1. It is better to keep the time reference in the numerator and the denominator the same ('day' with a 'day') as opposed to change the time reference: ('day' with a 'day that I made up').

Are there other reasons that are relevant here?

Am I thinking about this in completely the wrong way?

Comment: I'm a little bit biased so I'll refrain from answering. But I'll note for Option 2 you'd probably want a weighted average and not a sum, where, to continue the analogy, you could weight by "active practices day x".